# Why this Java program hangs (asynchronous html downloader)?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Could you please tell me why this Java program hangs ?
It's a simple program to download HTML asynchronously using ExecutorCompletionService. I tried  to use `executor.shutdown()` and `completionService.shutdown()` but both give `no such method`. I think the problem is with `executor` and `completionService` but can't figure out how to stop them not using their shutdown method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
        completionService.submit(new GetPageTask(new URL("http://xn--80adxoelo.xn--p1ai/")));//slow web site
        completionService.submit(new GetPageTask(new URL("http://example.com")));

        Future<String> future = completionService.take();
        System.out.println(future.get());

        Future<String> future2 = completionService.take();
        System.out.println(future2.get());


    }
}

final class GetPageTask implements Callable<String> {
    private final URL url;

    GetPageTask(URL url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private String getPage() throws Exception {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.url.openStream()));
        String str = "";
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line + "\n";
        }
        reader.close();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return getPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hangs how? Does it print anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc of [Executors.newFixedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) says that it returns an instance of `ExecutorService`. The javadoc of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) shows that it has a `shutdown()` method.

You can't access it because you chose to declare your variable as `Executor` rather than `ExecutorService`.

Just like if you do

```
Object o = new Integer(34);
```

you won't be able to call any Integer method on `o`. Whereas if you do

```
Integer o = new Integer(34);
```

then you can use the Integer methods on o.

I don't want to be rude, but that's pretty basic stuff that you should master before thinking about multithreading programming, which is very, very complex.

Comment: Thank you. Replaced Executor with ExecutorService and added shutdown. Now it's fine.